# I'm using OpenAPI (Swagger) to generate my node-express code. I'm getting duplicate imports (modal) for this file (invites.ts)

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, swagger, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen

This is the config for swagger ui
**/schema/config.yaml**

```
Invite:
  type: object
  x-mongo-schema: true
  properties:
    uid:
      type: string
      description: The unique identifier of the invite.
    sequence:
      type: number
      description: The sequence number of the cal invite.

Invites:
  type: object
  x-mongo-schema: true
  properties:
    participant:
      $ref: "#/components/schemas/Invite"
    researcher:
      $ref: "#/components/schemas/Invite"
```

the config for mustache for generating boilerplate code
**/cgen/generator_custom_templates/config.yaml**

```
templateDir: ./cgen/generator_custom_templates/templates
files:
  .env.example: {}
  authz.mustache:
    folder: controllers
    destinationFilename: authz.ts
    templateType: SupportingFiles
```

This is the script I ran to generate the boilerplate code
script:

```
java -jar ./cgen/openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g nodejs-express-server -i ./schemas/index.yaml -c ./cgen/generator_custom_templates/config.yaml -o ./generated_code --skip-operation-example
```

generated file: invites.ts

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { inviteSchema, IInvite } from '#models/invite'; // Need to fix this Duplicate import

import { inviteSchema, IInvite } from '#models/invite'; // Need to fix this Duplicate import

export interface IInvites {
  participant?: IInvite,

  researcher?: IInvite,

};

export const invitesSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IInvites>(
  {
    participant: { type: inviteSchema, },

    researcher: { type: inviteSchema, },

  },
  { _id: false }
);
```

Comment: I solved it, although it is a hack.
Hey, currently there's an open discussion regarding this Duplicate Import issue.
What I did was I ran eslint in my generated code file i.e. invites.ts file to remove duplicate imports with 'eslint --fix' command

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, although it is a hack. Hey, currently there's an open discussion regarding this Duplicate Import issue. What I did was I ran eslint in my generated code file i.e. invites.ts file to remove duplicate imports with 'eslint --fix' command